# Rails asset pipeline: how to create custom manifest file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, sprockets, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am trying to make a custom manifest javascript file seperate from application.js.  I've take the code from application.js and pasted it into a new file I've called "other_manifest.js" and placed in the assets/javascrips directory.  Here is the code:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

In my assets.rb file, I've included the line:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(other_manifest.js)
```

I precompile and clean the assets locally, and then when I run the page, all i get is the exact text from the manifest file.  It is not bringing in any of the files.  How do I create a custom manifest file?

Comment: did you replace `application.js` in your `app/views/layouts/application.html` file ?

Comment: I put in an if/else so depending on the page, application.js shows up or other_manifest.js shows up

Answer (score 4):

Easily

You have `application.js`. Create a second file: `other_manifest.js`

Then in your layout `layouts/application.html.erb` (could be a different layout altogether):

```
<% if condition %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'other_manifest' %>
<% else %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
<% end %>
```

And yes, you need to add in your `config/initializers/assets.rb` (followed by reboot):

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(other_manifest.js)
```

Also, make sure to remove the `//= require_tree .` from manifests. Because it will include ALL the javascript in the manifest (making having a different manifest pointless)

Comment: I am trying to do this but still need to include the require_tree . and that appears to be breaking this with the following error: Sprockets::CircularDependencyError in Index#index .. I need the require_tree . to work because there are about 100+ angular files in the assets/javascripts folder and the differences I need have been added via bower_components and live in a separate directory.. thoughts?

Comment: @Starfs `require_tree . ` will require the other JS manifest file. Put all the shared JS into a shared directory and then do `require_tree ./shared` or something of that nature

Comment: @Rusian as a side note I still had trouble making this work, but eventually just imported scripts in /views/layout/application.html.erb <% if mobile_device == "mobile" %><script src ="..  etc snd it is the way to go!

Comment: @Starfs Just be careful when you deploy to production with asset pipeline. Because `application.js` will turn to `application-2sadf324gsx234dfasdf.......js`

Comment: It seems like you're describing the very thing the OP tried, which didn't work for them. This approach does not seem to work.